# Access the choice via my django model

Tags: python, django

### settings.py

```
PERIODS = (
    ('day', _('Per day')),
    ('week', _('Per week')),
    ('month', _('Per month')),
    ('year', _('Per year')), 
)
```

### models.py

```
class Statistics(TimeStampedModel):

    @property
    def per_period(self):
        return settings.PERIODS[self.] 

    def nb_of_customers_per_period(self):
        pass
```

### views.py

```
class StatisticsIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Statistics()
    template_name = 'loanwolf/statistics/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StatisticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'applications_by_state': ApplicationsByState(),
            'applications_calendar': ApplicationsCalendar(),
            'new_customers_calendar': NewCustomersCalendar(),
            'statistics': Statistics(),
            'form': StatisticsBaseForm(),
        })
        return context
```

### forms.py

```
class StatisticsBaseForm(forms.Form):
    type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, initial=0, required=False)
    period = forms.ChoiceField(label="Period", choices=settings.PERIODS, initial='week', required=False)
    from_regular_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProductConfig.objects.filter(pk=-1), required=False,
        label=_('Product'))
    from_special_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProductConfig.objects.filter(pk=-1), required=False,
        label=_('Product'))
    product_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=settings.LOANWOLF_PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES, required=False,
        initial='regular', label=_('Product type'))
    debit_frequency = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=settings.LOANWOLF_PRODUCT_DEBIT_FREQUENCIES_CHOICES,
        required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatisticsBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'row'
        self.helper.layout = StatisticalToolsLayout

        company = get_current_company()
        regular_products = company.available_products.filter(
            is_active=True, product_type='regular')
        special_products = company.available_products.filter(
            is_active=True, product_type='special')

        self.fields['from_regular_product'].queryset = regular_products
        self.fields['from_special_product'].queryset = special_products

        if regular_products:
            self.fields['from_regular_product'].initial = \
                settings.LOANWOLF_EXTERNAL_REQUEST_DEFAULT_PRODUCT_INDEX

        if special_products:
            self.fields['from_special_product'].initial = \
                settings.LOANWOLF_EXTERNAL_REQUEST_DEFAULT_PRODUCT_INDEX

    class Meta:
        model = Statistics
        fields = '__all__'
```

Ok, here is my problem. I have a [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKwG7.png) with a `period` drop-down menu which allows me to select different types of period (`Per day`, `Per week`, `Per month` or `Per year`). For instance, if I select `Per week`, I would like to have access to this choice through `Statistics` model with self.something. Sorry in advance, but I am a very new programmer in Django/Python. How could I do such thing? Do I need to send something with the `Apply` button from the [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKwG7.png)?

### Update

In my django project, it is possible to show every customer in the application with `CustomerProfile.objects.all()` and find the creation date of a specific customer with

```
In [12]: cust = CustomerProfile.objects.get(pk=100)

In [13]: cust.user.date_joined
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548)

In [14]: cust
Out[14]: <CustomerProfile: FistName LastName's customer profile>
```

According to the creation date, I would like to make a listing of how many customers has been created per day, week, month or year. An example of the result could be

```
...
week 28 : [ 09/07/2017 - 15/07/2017 ] - Count : 201 customers
...
```

I probably need a range start_date and end_date where we will list that kind of information. start_date will be the date of the first customer created and the first week create would be the week of this first date. Obviously, the end_date is today and the last week est the week of this end_date.

For instance, if I select `Per week` in the drop-down menu and press `Apply` in the form, I want to send information to my model in such I could code what I explained.

Comment: Do you have any fields in your ```Statistics``` model?

Comment: No, I don't have any fields for the moment in my `Statistics` model. Yes, I have a views to display and handel the post of that form. The view is in the question .

Comment: I don't get the property if you don't have any fields or attribute in an ```__init__``` function. You want to save the choice in a Statistic row that's it?

Comment: This is probably something I misunderstanding so far.  If you can show me the good procedure, it'd be appreciated.  Yes, I want to save the choice in a Statistic row. In fact, if I select the `Per week` option, I would like to show  the number of customer create each week. So I don't think it is necessary to reserve place in the database for that

Comment: @Bestasttung Will you answer that question?

Comment: Hum i must it's quite complicated, and from what i see you have some choices of period for products, but you're talking about the number of customers created in a period. I must say i'm a bit confused.

Comment: Ok, maybe  it could be relevant to update that question. Let me 5 minutes please. I think you have the knowledge  to explain well to me, but my question is unclear.

Comment: tried to answer, tell me if it's still not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you can add a save() method in your form :

```
class StatisticsBaseForm(forms.Form):
    ... # the rest of the code
    def save(self):
        period = self.cleaned_data['period']
        # do something with the period
        get_user_create_by_period(period)
```

And add this form in your views like this:

```
class StatisticsIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Statistics
    template_name = 'loanwolf/statistics/index.html'
    form_class = StatisticsBaseForm
```

The save method of the form will be called when the view will have checked if all data submited are ok. There, in the save() method of your form, you have access to the submitted data, like `self.cleaned_data['period']`

I actually even think the Statistics model is useless here.

Comment: Why do you think Statistics model is useless? Is not in a model class I need to implement the logic?

Comment: you just want to display the number of user? you don't want to store the result anywhere? It's just when someone submit your form, you want to display the number of user created in the period chosen?

Comment: No, in fact it is a little more complicated than that. I need to implement statistical indicator with the number of user. No, I don't need to store the result anywhere. Yes, I want to display the number of user created in the period chosen

Comment: So what fields do you need in you Statistical model ? period, a date, and a result for when the result is about?

Comment: Sorry, I mislead! I need to store the informations about the number of user per period. Or maybe I could compute them each time the `Apply` button is selected

Comment: That was just an example. I told you here you can call your calculation method. But  you have to implement it

Comment: But that the way I have to 'fetch' the informations from the form about the `Apply` button right? I mean if I want to use it directly in the django class, right?

Comment: when you click on apply, the form post the value you've typed, the view receive it, save the form (and here i show you how to override the save method and access to the submitted data) and you can do your calculation.

Comment: Ok, It is clear to me. According to you, where do I need to implement `get_user_create_by_period()`?

Comment: you can do that in you Customer model. That would make sense, or actually in the form. It's not really a method of Customer, or make it static.